# Will youtube address with only code usually work?

Tags: regex, url, youtube

In setting up a part of a site where users can enter url for youtube video and have it play in modal window -- currently using fancybox -- have found that some urls don't work, even with fancybox regex for the href.
However, it appears that just getting the video's code and appending it to a basic url stem works. Such as:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video code}
as in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMYzsAurxHY

I run the submitted url through a series of ColdFusion regexs to get the code, and then append to the "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="  stem.

Note having any problems, but just want to see if anyone more familiar with youtube sees any problem with assuming this stem + video code wouldn't always work -- or at least a great percentage of the time.

Thanks

Comment: Could it be that the videos that don't work have embedding disabled?

Comment: didn't do enough testing all the commonalities for those that work (although "player_embedded" in URL seemed to be one). Right now not concerned about what isn't working. Just whether my basic URL (stem plus video code) should usually go to right place. The fancybox player seems to like that format.